# delete file - specific date

Tags: shell

How to Delete file created in a specific date??

`ls -ltr | grep "Nov 22" | rm` -- why this is not wrking??

Comment: The problem with your code is that `rm` does not take input on stdin (via the pipe), you must pass the files to remove as arguments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are three problems with your code:

- `rm` takes its arguments on its command line, but you're not passing any file name on the command line. You are passing data on the standard input, but `rm` doesn't read that¹. There are ways around this.
- The output of `ls -ltr | grep "Nov 22"` doesn't just consist of file names, it consists of [mangled](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) file names plus a bunch of other information such as the time.
- The grep filter won't just catch files modified on November 22; it will also catch files whose name contains `Nov 22`, amongst others. It also won't catch the files you want in a locale that displays dates differently.

The `find` command lets you search files according to criteria such as their name matching a certain pattern or their date being in a certain range. For example, the following command will list the files in the current directory and its subdirectories that were modified today (going by GMT calendar date). Replace `echo` by `rm --` once you've checked you have the right files.

```
find . -type f -mtime -2 -exec echo {} +
```

With GNU find, such as found on Linux and Cygwin, there are a few options that might do a better job:

- `-maxdepth 1` (must be specified before other criteria) limits the search to the specified directory (i.e. it doesn't recurse).
- `-mmin -43` matches files modified at most 42 minutes ago.
- `-newermt "Nov 22"` matches files modified on or after November 22 (local time).

Thus:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt "Nov 22" \! -newermt "Nov 23" -exec echo {} +
```

or, further abbreviated:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt "Nov 22" \! -newermt "Nov 23" -delete
```

With zsh, the `m` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#SEC87) limits a pattern to files modified within a certain relative date range. For example, `*(m1)` expands to the files modified within the last 24 hours; `*(m-3)` expands to the files modified within the last 48 hours (first the number of days is rounded up to an integer, then `-` denotes a strict inequality); `*(mm-6)` expands to the files modified within the last 5 minutes, and so on.

¹ <sub>`rm -i` (and plain `rm` for read-only files) uses it to read a confirmation `y` before deletion.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

If you need to try find for any given day,
this might help

```
touch -d "2010-11-21 23:59:59" /tmp/date.start;
touch -d "2010-11-23 00:00:00" /tmp/date.end;
find ./ -type f -newer /tmp/date.start ! -newer /tmp/date.end -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Terminate -exec with a `+` instead of `\;` and you'll get a performance boost when you match many files as it behaves just like `xargs` in that respect.

Answer (score 2):

If your `find` supports it, as GNU `find` does, you can use:

```
find -type f -newermt "Nov 21" ! -newermt "Nov 22" -delete
```

which will find files that were modified on November 21.

Comment: Worth to mention -newermt support for version 4.3.3 onwards

Answer (score 1):

You would be better suited to use the `find` command:

```
find . -type f -mtime 1 -exec echo rm {} +
```

This will delete all files one day old in the current directory and recursing down into its sub-directories.  You can use '0' if you want to delete files created today. Once you are satisfied with the output, remove the `echo` and the files will truly be deleted.

Comment: thanks for you reply Siegex, but can you tell me wats the prblm with my code

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in  `ls -ltr | grep "NOV 23" | awk '{print $9}'` 
do 
    rm -rf $i 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Mb better

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for i in  $(ls -ltr | grep "NOV 23" | awk '{print $9}') 
do 
    rm -rf $i 
done
```

then in the previous comment